# Node.js library for geospatial operations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, node.js, geospatial

I am developing an application where I have geospatial polygons like this:

```
var polygon = [{"lat": -19.939323, "lng": -43.928983},
               {"lat": -19.939747, "lng": -43.933103},
               {"lat": -19.947291, "lng": -43.93497},
               {"lat": -19.948138, "lng": -43.931451},
               {"lat": -19.943882, "lng": -43.930292}]
```

I will receive a coordinate to say if is inside, or not, the polygon. I found, in Geometry Library of Google Maps Javascript API, a function who does exactly the same thing: [containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

But this must be server-side, using node.js, is there a way to use this function on node.js, or better, is there a good library who does that?

Answer (score 15):

There are a few node modules, such as [geolib](https://npmjs.org/package/geolib):

> Library to provide basic geospatial operations like distance calculation, conversion of decimal coordinates to sexagesimal and vice versa, etc.

which have an equivalent function to determine coordinates relative to a polygon.

**References**

- [geolib Github repo](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib)
- [geojson-js-utils Github repo](https://github.com/maxogden/geojson-js-utils)
- [geojson-vt Github repo](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt)